# Getting error for password field alone in RTL for arabic language

Tags: android, android-edittext, arabic, right-to-left

For password Edittext box alone not working Rtl properly. I have tried all solution which is in stackoverflow. Am working app with muti language support both English and arabic. Please help me :(

Comment: I'm afraid you'll need to clarify your post if you want people to help: please define what "not working properly" means (which error do you get?) and which solutions you have tried.

Comment: can you tell about what ways do you tried so that we can avoid posting that

Answer (score 1):

i faced a similar issue while developing an app In Arabic and English and i could only manage it programmatically by checking system lang like:

```
//check sys lang
    public boolean isArabic()
    {
        if (Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().equals("ar")) {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {return false;}
    }
```

then set your gravity to edittext accordingly

```
if(isArabic())
        {
        //arabic (rtl)
            edtPassword.setGravity(Gravity.END);
        }
        else {
        //english (ltr)
            edtPassword.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
        }
```

Comment: @a.toraby it's a quite old answer. Maybe recently there are some changes in behaviour